# Quicksort in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I'm new to openMP and I'm trying to implement quicksort in it.

I understand that I have to select one pivot and then sort the equal parts of the array in parallel. Then I have to reorder the array. However after doing this I need to know the indexes on which the threads are supposed to start and stop in the next step.

I've found that you have to use prefix sum somehow to keep information about the indexes but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: *I'm new to openMP and I'm trying to implement quicksort in it.*  Don't.  It is very difficult to parallelise quicksort effectively, especially so in OpenMP whose parallelisation 'model' is quite different to that necessary for quicksort.  Definitely not a task for a beginner.  Use your favourite search engine on *parallel sort algorithms* and choose a different approach.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for your answer. I have found a lot of different sorting algorithms but they are usually very badly described. Could you please give me a link to any of them described really simply?

Comment: No, SO isn't here to replace search engines and if I try to break the rules I'm scared that the moderators will be nasty to me.  I might start my own (re-)search at a well-known user-written online encyclopaedia though.